# Vpn between two workers node

Tags: istio

I have three nodes, the master and two workers inside my cluster. I want to know if it's possible with **Istio** to redirect all the traffic comming from one worker node, directly to the other worker node (but not the traffic of Kubernetes).

Thanks for the help

Warok

**Edit**
Apparently, it's possible to route the traffic of one specific user to a specific version https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/request-routing/#route-based-on-user-identity. But the question is still open

**Edit 2**
Assume that my nodes name are node1 and node2, does the following yaml file is right?

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v2alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: node1
  ...
spec:
  hosts:
  - nod1
  tcp:
  -match:
    -port: 27017 #for now, i will just specify this port
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: node2
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if it's possible with **Istio** to redirect all the traffic comming from one worker node, directly to the other worker node (but not the traffic of Kubernetes).

Quick answer, No.

Istio is working as a sidecar container that is injected into a `pod`. You can read at [What is Istio?](https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/)

> Istio lets you connect, secure, control, and observe services.
>
> ...
>
> It is also a platform, including APIs that let it integrate into any logging platform, or telemetry or policy system. Istio’s diverse feature set lets you successfully, and efficiently, run a distributed microservice architecture, and provides a uniform way to secure, connect, and monitor microservices.
>
> ...
>
> You add Istio support to services by deploying a special sidecar proxy throughout your environment that intercepts all network communication between microservices

I also recommend reading [What is Istio? The Kubernetes service mesh explained](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3328817/what-is-istio-the-kubernetes-service-mesh-explained.html).

It's also important to know why would you want to redirect traffic from one node to the other.

Without knowing that I cannot advice any solutions.

Comment: I'm implementing Edge computing. I used https://kubeedge.io/en/ to create my cluster with edges nodes (edge node 1 and edge node 2) on differents subnets and geographically separeted.
The purpose of this project is to make the traffic (the one from edge node 1 to edge node 2 and reciprocally) communicate directly without going to the central edge wich is more far away than the two edges nodes

Comment: Hope this will help

Comment: Sorry but I've never heard of kubeedge, You could use [Cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) to scale nodes on desired location and use [affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) for pod assignment to nodes. Other then that I don't really know how to help you with this.